# UITableView deselect row works but won't animate in iOS14

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, uikit

This is a weird one. On iOS 14 only.

**Context**

- MainViewController (`UIViewController`, NOT a `UITableViewController`) with a `UITableView` and a `UIView` containing some buttons
- The tableView is populated using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the delegate being the MainViewController
- DetailsViewController that gets pushed (no segue) on tableView didSelectRow

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let document = CoreDataManager.shared.frc.object(at: indexPath)
        // Pass model
        self.detailsVC.model = model
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.detailsVC, animated: true)
    }
```

**Issue**

When navigating back to the MainViewController, I can't get the selected row **to animate**. It gets properly deselected though.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // Deselect selected row
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) // animated flag is set to true... to normally get an animation
        }
    }
```

**What I already tried**

- Deselecting in `viewWillAppear` --> same result, deselection OK, animation NOT OK
- Ensured there is no tableView.reloadData() happening

**Extra info**

I just discovered that the selection animation also does not work.
On iOS 13, it works fine.

I don't know what to do anymore. I'd love to have the usual nice animation when navigating back (example: the Contacts app).
Thanks!

Comment: did you set selectionStyle of your UITableViewCell to none?

Comment: try creating a clean project, and if you can reproduce the problem there - add the link here. If you'll have troubles in reproducing it, try adding core data to see if it's related. If this's still not reproduced, try creating an empty view controller in your app with a plain table, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `selectionStyle` property of your cell is not set to `.none`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's set to `.default`. Tried other values, same issue.

Comment: Does `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` return `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's guided project at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views.

You'll find this code snippet, among many other useful ones:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
        if let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
                self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }) { (context) in
                if context.isCancelled {
                    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Which adapted for table views should look like follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.first {
        if let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }) { (context) in
                if context.isCancelled {
                    self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

And it seems to work.